# Authentication problem with IBM DB2 on Mac

Tags: docker, authentication, installation, db2, macos-catalina

I have installed DB2 successfully on my Mac based on this link and it worked fine: https://ajstorm.medium.com/installing-db2-on-your-coffee-break-5be1d811b052

Then, I was trying to install and connect to DB2 via DB2 Connect extension from VSCode. The installation did not work so I returned to Terminal to continue coding with DB2 on there, I encounter the error as in the image below (authentication problem). Maybe it's about the Docker that has the issue? Any pro could help me with this, please? Thank you.

SQL1366N  A security plug-in "IBMLDAPauthclient" processing error occurred on the client. Reason code = "7".

[Error Message from Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkmHA.png)

Comment: This might be a known bug, IT37032 for which the fix is available via service to level 11.5.7.0 available from fix central. If you are already at that level (use the `db2level` command in the container to see the current level), then we would need to see what entries of type Error are appended to the Db2 diagnostics file on the server , and on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm already 11.5.7.0 level. But I'm not sure what to do from here. I tried to remove the docker container and reinstall DB2 again but the same error happened

Comment: Please edit your question to show the Error events (not the info messages, or warning messages) that get added to the db2diag after the clp attempts to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the thing by:

- Go to docker desktop and delete the DB2 container
- Reinstall DB2 using the instructions from: https://javamana.com/2022/03/202203170730500825.html#4%E3%80%81%E5%88%9B%E5%BB%BA%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E5%BA%93%C2%A0
- Except for the final step, I just created a new database after the "CREATE DATABASE AUDIT" part and use the newly created database there.

n.b: this is just to have DB2 functioning so that I can do homework assignment. If you require to fix the issue for work, this might not be a good idea.

Thank you.